# AFNetworking NSThread

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsthread

I'm researching AFNetworking and noticed that it creates it's own NSThread.  As far as I know apple discourages using NSThread now.  Is this acceptable practice for AFNetworking to create is's own NSThread?  Is this going to change in a future release?

Thanks

```
+ (NSThread *)networkRequestThread {
    static NSThread *_networkRequestThread = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _networkRequestThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:) object:nil];
        [_networkRequestThread start];
    });

    return _networkRequestThread;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should post this question on the [AFNetworking Github Issues page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues) if you want insights on the developers' plans, but in answer to your question, Apple's counsel about [Migrating Away From Threads](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) is driven by the fact that writing `NSThread` code is complicated and operation queues and dispatch queues are a much easier and safer way to write multithreaded code. They're not (in my reading, at least) saying that you can't use `NSThread`, just that there are generally much easier ways to do what we used to do with threads.

Bottom line, using [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in background queues requires care. If you simply create a simple, delegate-based connection from a background queue, you'll find that your delegate methods may not be called. The `AFNetworking` technique is a perfectly acceptable solution to this problem.